# Open YouTube URL in Safari instead of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, youtube

I'm trying to load any URL, after the initial load, in Safari. With any other webpage, this code works fine:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL* url = [request URL];
    if (UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But as soon as I head over to m.youtube.com, the code no longer does anything, and YouTube continues to load inside the UIWebView. I can't find anything about this online. Any help?

Here is my entire .m file:

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController
@synthesize topLayer = _topLayer;
@synthesize layerPosition = _layerPosition;
@synthesize webView = webView;

#define VIEW_HIDDEN 260

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    webView.delegate = self;

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.youtube.com"]]];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [webView setOpaque:NO];
    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
    webView.scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;


    [self performSelector:@selector(makeTick)];

    self->promoteImages.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1920, 101);

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Scroll3.png"]];

    [self->promoteImages addSubview:imageView];

    [promoteImages setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

And here's my .h file for the View Controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *promoteImages;
    NSTimer *time;

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}

@property (nonatomic, nonatomic) UIWebView *webView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *topLayer;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat layerPosition;
@property(nonatomic,readonly,getter=isDragging)    BOOL dragging;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that I use:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Here's your problem:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Change to:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
```

You can also specify only certain URLs to open in Safari, for example any URLS beginning with `http://www.example.com/share` as shown here:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        if ((navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) && ([currentURL hasPrefix:@"http://www.example.com/share"])) {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
            return NO;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does exactly the same thing - every website except YouTube opens in Safari after I click a link.

Comment: Are you saying that the YouTube link loads inside of the YouTube app? Or inside of a webView within your app?

Comment: It loads inside the webView.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the code above in the View Controller of the view that the link actually appears in? And... you have `UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked == navigationType` whereas it should be flipped to `navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked`

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I can't really help - what I showed should work perfectly, as it does in my app.

Comment: The only thing I see different is that in your .h file, change the webView call to `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView;`

Comment: I changed it and still nothing. Does yours work with the mobile youtube site? Is it possible?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23243/discussion-between-adam-d-and-stickerbox)